# set fontfamily from resources

Tags: c#, silverlight, font-family

I have tried several different ways set to fontfamily of my textblock to a font that is in my resources.

I must add the font family programatically and not based on xaml.

I have to font added to my resources and in my solution explorer my font is located in..

PROJECT NAME > Resource

The name of my font is MYFONT.ttf

i thought this would work but it didnt

```
BLOCK.FontFamily = new FontFamily("{StaticResource MYFONT}")
BLOCK.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Resources/MYFONT.ttf")
```

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, rather than as an edit to your question (you can access what you wrote here; https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23747993/3).